# ellipsis does not work (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I'm trying to put ellipsis for text overflow:

parent:

```
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
}
```

child:

```
.grid-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-basis: 0;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.grid-cell:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And, well the `overflow` is `hidden`, but without any ellipsis.

Comment: Many flexbox / ellipsis posts. One of [**these**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3597276+%5Bflexbox%5D+ellipsis) may help (and be a duplicate)..

Comment: Without the HTML, the problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *text overflow* to work you need a set `width` - set a `width` to your `grid-row`.

Also remove the `display: flex` from the `grid-cell` - see demo below:

```css
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
}
.grid-cell {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-basis: 0;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.grid-cell:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="grid-cell">insert text here</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">some text</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">some more text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the question he needed the cell to be display: flex, asking to remove it makes the answer irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
.grid-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-basis: 0;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap:normal;
  width: ###px;
}
```

You should set the `width` of `.grid-cell`

Comment: tried. does not work

Comment: @Chen Try to add width.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .grid-cell:

```
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.